# XenServer shared drive configuration

Tags: samba, xenserver, nfs

I have a server with below configuration

```
Intel Xeon E3 - 1230
2 * (Seagate 1 TeraByte)  = total two terabyte
16 GB Ram
```

My Requirement : I need to run XenServer on this box and run 4 Ubuntu Virtual Machines and 1 windows VM.

I need to set about 750GB space for common share across all Virtual Machines. All the VMS need to read and write data from the common space. I intend to use NFS or Samba.

**My Questions :**

1. What is better NFS or Samba ?
2. One approach : I create a new Ubuntu VM and allocate about 750GB to it. I run NFS server on this VM and all other VMs just mount and use the space.
   Second Approach : I can allocate the space to XenServer itself and run the NFS server on it.

Please suggest if there is any better solution than above two Or the best solution among the above two.

Answer (score 1):

Re #1: With no other information to go on, I would likely pick Samba for your situation if forced to pick one, simply because samba support in linux is probably better than NFS support in Windows.  However, if you have the option, why not support both?

Re #2: Create a new VM to host the storage.  Running extra services within XenServer's dom0 is neither recommended nor supported by Citrix.